Setting the nesting level of a link in the address bar
I have a link of this type:
site.com/country/news/article-1.html
And I need to make it look like this:
site.com/country/article-1.html
It means that there was only the very first parent in the address bar, well, and accordingly the last element regardless of the nesting level colo-va level
How can this be realized?

Set "Use current alias in alias path" flag for "country" resources to 0.

